# Error while getting native targets for android: No valid Android SDK root found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run the command:

> ionic cordova run android

and this error always appears:

> [ERROR] Error while getting native targets for android: No valid
> Android SDK root found.
>
> This error occurred while using native-run. You can try running this command with --no-native-run, which will
> revert to using Cordova.

Environment:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.3, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.2
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 2.15.12
   OS     : Linux 4.15
```

~/.bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export ANDROID_HOME="~/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="~/Android/Sdk"

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
```

Comment: I've tried adding npm i -g native-run and it didn't work

Comment: Seems like 2 issues: 1st: you don't need `ANDROID_HOME` remove it. 2nd: `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin` remove `/bin` from this line.

Answer (score 3):

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Just use this code and plugin in your device hope its work

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the Cordova platform with the commands:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@10
```

the android application now could be built successfully with Cordova and API 29.